# Tab's title is not flashing in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm going to show "New message..." in title every second when browser tab is inactive or user is in other tabs. I used this:

```
  <script>
    var mytimer;

    function log() {

        document.title = document.title == "" ? "New message..." : "";

    }

    $(window).focusout(function () {
        mytimer=setInterval(function () {
            log();
        }, 1000);
    }).focusin(function () {
                clearInterval(mytimer);
            });


</script>
```

when user leaves current tab it starts to work but when it comes back to the tab it doesn't stop. Any idea what is wrong with that?

**Solution:**

I just changed `focusout` method to `blur` and `focusin` to `focus` and started to work in Firefox. In IE and Chrome works properly.

Comment: Also make sure your jQuery code is contained in a doc ready. `$(function(){ /* code */ });` http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the `setInterval` to `myTimer`.

```
mytimer = setInterval(function () {
   log()
}, 1000);
```

Added a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMLvs/2/)**;
Focus the output window by clicking on it, and unfocus by clicking another frame.

Comment: `myTimer` should be `mytimer` with lowercase t

Comment: I just edited my question. it works in Chrome & IE but not in Firefox! why? @user887675

Comment: Just installed Firefox to check; it seems Firefox fires the events multiple times. To prevent that, I've added an extra `clearInterval`. http://jsfiddle.net/JMLvs/2/

Comment: @user887675  It's a good idea to update your answer with new fiddle and explanation why you added `clearInterval`.  Updates in comments often tend to go ignored.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Tested and working in chrome,firefox,ie, and opera. Flashes back and forth between original title and `New Message` like on irc.

```
$(function(){
    var title = $('title').html();
    var thread = null;
    $(window).focusout(function () {
        var i = 0;
        thread = setInterval(function(){
            if(i % 2 == 0 || i == 0){ 
                $('title').html("New Message..");
            }else{
                $('title').html(title); 
            }
            i++;
        },500); 
    }).focusin( function(){ 
        clearInterval(thread);
        $('title').html(title);
    });
});
```

Comment: Like I suspected,  this will not reset to original title on returning to the tab in subject.  I tried this on Firefox 30,  Windows7.  Also, from what I understand,  he is looking for a blinking effect on the title of tab.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr thanks for the heads up. i'll make a fiddle and see if i can't work something out.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr i got it finally

Comment: +1 fro the efforts.  I haven't checked this but from here,  I can't say if this will reset the title to original on focus on tab.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr it does, however selecting the address bar causes the title to go crazy in chrome. https://openex.info/test.php